# Realization relationship && Association relationship in software engineering

Tags: uml, class-diagram, rup

You might know that Association relationship is a structural relationship  which one of the classes knows about the information in another class But if you can please tell an example that I can understand it and I need to know about Realization relationship with an example ,too .
I will appreciate you if you can tell some examples.

Answer (score 1):

In the UML Specification by OMG defines Realization as below:

> Realization is a specialized abstraction relationship between two sets
>   of model elements, one representing a specification (the supplier) and
>   the other represents an implementation of the latter (the client).
>   Realization can be used to model stepwise refinement, optimizations,
>   transformations, templates, model synthesis, framework composition,
>   etc.

Also as specialized classes, there are ComponentRealization, InterfaceRealization, Substitution and InterfaceRealization is the most useful one for designing the programs.

> An InterfaceRealization is a specialized Realization relationship
>   between a Classifier and an Interface. This relationship signifies
>   that the realizing classifier conforms to the contract specified by
>   the Interface.

[image]

Comment: thank u but if it is possible describe it  more on your diagram??

Comment: This diagram represents that "DiagramElement Class" implements Resizable and Movable Interfaces. Dotted line is an InterfaceRealization.